# Why am I getting `NOT NULL constraint failed` error with Django?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django. I am to create some sort of todo app. I am having trouble setting `IntegerField` as optional field. As far as I can see the problem is when I try to save to save the object to the database. I get error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: lista_row.quantity`. I have made (and migrated) migrations. Here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Row(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=True)
```

Comment: `null=False` You told Django that this column must not be null, and then you tried to create a row where this column was null.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it optional, use this instead:
`quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`